# Changing FlowDirection of a cell in Wpf's DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I Have a DataGrid with its FlowDirection set to "RightToLeft". Problem is when displaying negative numbers, the minus sign is shown on the opposite side. 
Setting the FlowDirection of the cell itself to "LeftToRight" fixes it, but then the left border of the cell moves to the right, so I have no border on the left, and a double border on the right.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're gonna have to set FlowDirection on the TextBox rather than on the DataGridCell. If you're using a DataGridTextColumn then

```
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks Meleak! Right now I'm using DataGridTemplateColumn instead of the TextColumn, which solves the issue, but I prefer using the TextColumn. I'll give it a try.